# python requests post query fails:cookies?

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to execute this `post` but I get `server error 500`:

```
import requests
base_url = "https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx"
url = "%s/%s"% (base_url,"GetCarBodyTypeListByCarAlim")
pars ={"CarAlim":"DIES","CarType": "A7", "CodeMake": "AUDI", "FirstDrivingDate": "2015-09-22"}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.post(url,data=pars)
    print r.status_code

 ## 500
```

I think I need to set cookies or something else.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: try using a session object. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

Comment: Why do you think you need set cookies? A HTTP server is a black box and it can respond to any request however the hell they see fit. You need to experiment as to what combination of headers and body data it'll accept and what it won't. Many servers are configured to only accept requests from certain `User-Agent` headers, for example (client whitelisting), for example. You'll need to compare your `requests` requests with requests from other clients that work, and try out what differences between the two matter.

Comment: Currently, I can't even get the site to work in my *browser*. It looks to me that the site is *broken*, and thus there won't be any way to get a result out of that site with `requests` either.

Comment: Last but not least, the site also supports SOAP requests. Have you tried using that API instead of using POST with x-www-form-urlencoded data?

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you for you interset. What do you mean by SOAP here? Which API?

Comment: @agstudy: my French is a little rusty but I see SOAP documentation on the [main API page](https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx). There are [several SOAP client libraries for Python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices).

Comment: @MartijnPieters maybe your french is not very good but I think you find a solution. How can I reward the bounty can you convert your comment to an answer please , with/without a code?

Comment: @agstudy: I tried to access the `GetMainCarMakeListByFirstDrivingDate` endpoint with the `zeep` client library, and that fails too. I've checked the SOAP message being sent, and I see nothing wrong, so this does very much look like the service is simply broken. Either contact the site operators or move on.

Comment: @agstudy: nonetheless, I typed out my findings below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most API access points on that site appear to be broken. There is nothing wrong with your code per-se. I can't actually get the site to respond to *any requests in their own webinterface*, even when using a regular browser.

The [main API documentation](https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx) details (in French) that you can also use the [SOAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) to create queries; Python has [several SOAP client libraries](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebServices) you could choose from.

However, I've had no luck in getting that to work *either*. Using the excellent [`zeep` library](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) I tried to access the simpler [`GetMainCarMakeListByFirstDrivingDate` endpoint](https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx?op=GetMainCarMakeListByFirstDrivingDate) (note that I had to use a `datetime()` object to model the timestamp):

```
>>> from zeep import Client
>>> client = Client('https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx?WSDL')
>>> client.service.GetMainCarMakeListByFirstDrivingDate(FirstDrivingDate=datetime(2015, 9, 22))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/client.py", line 25, in __call__
    self._op_name, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 109, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 145, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 223, in process_error
    detail=fault_node.find('detail'))
zeep.exceptions.Fault: <exception str() failed>
```

a `Fault` is the SOAP equivalent of a 500 error here.

When I [enable debug logging](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/transport.html#debugging), we can see that the server is having problems producing a response:

```
>>> client.service.GetMainCarMakeListByFirstDrivingDate(FirstDrivingDate=datetime(2015, 9, 22))
zeep.transports: HTTP Post to https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx:
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:GetMainCarMakeListByFirstDrivingDate xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ns0:FirstDrivingDate>2015-09-22T00:00:00</ns0:FirstDrivingDate>
    </ns0:GetMainCarMakeListByFirstDrivingDate>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>

zeep.transports: HTTP Response from https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx (status: 500):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Le serveur n'a pas pu traiter la demande. ---&gt; Erreur lors de la génération du document XML. ---&gt; Le type common.FormDataListItem n'était pas attendu. Utilisez l'attribut XmlInclude ou SoapInclude pour spécifier les types qui ne sont pas connus statiquement.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/client.py", line 25, in __call__
    self._op_name, args, kwargs)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 109, in send
    return self.process_reply(client, operation_obj, response)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 145, in process_reply
    return self.process_error(doc, operation)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zeep/wsdl/bindings/soap.py", line 223, in process_error
    detail=fault_node.find('detail'))
zeep.exceptions.Fault: <exception str() failed>
```

Hidden in there is the error message:

> Le serveur n'a pas pu traiter la demande. ---> Erreur lors de la génération du document XML. ---> Le type common.FormDataListItem n'était pas attendu. Utilisez l'attribut XmlInclude ou SoapInclude pour spécifier les types qui ne sont pas connus statiquement.

or, with some Google Translate help, in English:

> The server could not process the request. ---> Error generating the XML document. ---> The type common.FormDataListItem was not expected. Use XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.

Since we are not sending any `common.FormDataListItem` types, *and* the message complains that no XML document could be *generated*, this looks like a server-side programming error to me.

There are methods that do work, either via SOAP:

```
>>> client.service.GetCarTypeListByCodeMake(CodeMake='BMW', FirstDrivingDate=datetime(2016, 1, 1))
['I3', 'I8', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M6', 'SERIE 1 II', 'SERIE 2', 'SERIE 3 VI', 'SERIE 4', 'SERIE 5', 'SERIE 6', 'SERIE 7', 'X1', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'Z4']
>>> client.service.GetAllCarTypeListByCodeMake(CodeMake='BMW')
['1502', '1600', '1602', '1800', '1802', '2000', '2002', '2500', '3,0', '3,3', '315', '316', '318', '320', '323', '324', '325', '328', '330', '518', '520', '523', '524', '525', '528', '530', '535', '540', '545', '550', '628', '630', '633', '635', '645', '650', '725', '728', '730', '732', '733', '735', '740', '745', '750', '760', '840', '850', 'I3', 'I8', 'L7', 'M2', 'M3', 'M4', 'M5', 'M535', 'M6', 'M635', 'SERIE 1', 'SERIE 1 II', 'SERIE 2', 'SERIE 3', 'SERIE 3 (SUITE)', 'SERIE 3 VI', 'SERIE 4', 'SERIE 5', 'SERIE 6', 'SERIE 7', 'X1', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'Z1', 'Z3', 'Z4', 'Z8']
```

or via posting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data with `requests`:

```
>>> response = requests.post('https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx/GetCarTypeListByCodeMake', data={'CodeMake': 'BMW', 'FirstDrivingDate': datetime(2016, 1, 1)})
>>> print(response.text)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">I3</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">I8</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">M2</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">M3</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">M4</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">M5</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">M6</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SERIE 1 II</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SERIE 2</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SERIE 3 VI</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SERIE 4</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SERIE 5</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SERIE 6</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">SERIE 7</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">X1</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">X3</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">X4</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">X5</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">X6</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Z4</anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

You'll probably have to contact the maintainers of this API to get this sorted out, this is not something you can get to work on the Python side.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I don't know if this can help but testing `GetCarTypeListByCodeMake` query from the browser:  https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx?op=GetCarTypeListByCodeMake` with `CodeMake=BMW` and `FirstDrivingDate=2016-01-01` works fine for me.

Comment: @agstudy: indeed, that function *does* work. More evidence that the site is simply broken.

Comment: @agstudy: interesting; when you enter invalid information into the [`GetCarAlimListByCarType`](https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx?op=GetCarAlimListByCarType) method, you get an empty response, but valid information gives you the error. This is 100% a bug on that site.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the date format that is badly handled in the site.

That error 500 carries this description:

```
Erreur lors de la g&#233;n&#233;ration du document XML. ---> Le type common.FormDataListItem n&#39;&#233;tait pas attendu. Utilisez l&#39;attribut XmlInclude ou SoapInclude pour sp&#233;cifier les types qui ne sont pas connus statiquement.
```

Try it from your browser on their page for a more user friendly debug:
https://www.assurland.com/ws/CarVehiculeSearch.asmx?op=GetCarBodyTypeListByCarAlim

Note: "attribut **XmlInclude** ou **SoapInclude** pour spécifier les types qui ne sont pas connus statiquement"

So I tried a little search to enter date in another format.

As example:

```
Fri, 19 Jan 2001
```

or `19 Jan 2001`

You get `200 OK` request - in this case an empty result.

[image]

Unfortunately after a certain year, it looks that format is also not accepted: 22 Sep 2001 yields 200 OK but 22 Sep 2015 no more - it goes until 
2008-12-31.

Try with another datetime format... But it looks there is anything there... take another site :)